# SQLite, my references doesn't work

Tags: database, sqlite, reference, indexing, constraints

I've a problem.
I want to create a table with 3 foreign key

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
CREATE TABLE "Dipendente" ("idDipendente" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                                                 "nome" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
                                                 "cognome" VARCHAR NOT NULL , 
                                                 "email" VARCHAR NOT NULL  UNIQUE , 
                                                 "password" VARCHAR NOT NULL , 
                                                 "tipo" VARCHAR NOT NULL );


CREATE TABLE "Prodotto" ("idProdotto" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                             "nome" VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                             "qta" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                             "prezzoUnita" FLOAT NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE "Fondo" ("idFondo" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                        "nome" VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                        "fondoDisponibile" FLOAT NOT NULL );

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Acquisto" (
    `idAcquisto`  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
    `idDipendente` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    `idProdotto` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    `idFondo` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    `qta` INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    `dataAcquisto` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,

   CONSTRAINT `fk_acquisto_dipendente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idDipendente` )
      REFERENCES `Dipendente` (`idDipendente` )
         ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
         ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `fk_acquisto_prodotto`
     FOREIGN KEY (`idProdotto` )
       REFERENCES `Prodotto` (`idProdotto` )
         ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
         ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_acquisto_fondo`
FOREIGN KEY (`idFondo` )
  REFERENCES `Fondo` (`idFondo` )
    ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE INDEX 'fk_acquisto_dipendente' ON 'Acquisto' ('idDipendente' ASC);
CREATE INDEX 'fk_acquisto_prodotto' ON 'Acquisto' ('idProdotto' ASC);
CREATE INDEX 'fk_acquisto_fondo' ON 'Acquisto' ('idFondo' ASC);
```

So, I want to set Acquisto (idDipendente, idProdotto, idFondo) to -1 value by defaul, but when I delete the Dipendente's row with idDipendente = 1 in the table Acquisto the field idDipendente is set to 1 yet. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Please remove extra code and leave only relevant bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the table "Acquisto", you have three foreign key references. Each column of those foreign key references has a default value of -1, which isn't (I presume) a valid value in any of the referenced tables.

In this specific case, if you first insert a row into "Dipendente", and that row has "idDipendente" of -1, then you can delete the row where "idDipendente" equals 1. When you do that, you'll find the default value of -1 in Acquisto.idDependente.

The short story is your foreign key reference doesn't prevent you from *declaring* a default value of -1, but it *does* prevent you from *using* it.

To set the values to NULL instead, you need to do something along these lines.

```
pragma foreign_keys = on;
create table a (id integer primary key);
insert into a values (1);
create table b (
  b_id integer primary key, 
  a_id integer references a(id) 
    on delete set null);
insert into b values (1, 1);
delete from a;
select * from b;

b_id        a_id      
----------  ----------
1
```

Comment: Ok, but practically I want to show with a query all the rows of Acquisto, with or without idDipendente, with or without idProdotto, with or without idFondo. I can also replace the default value with a null field and in the constraint set ON DELETE SET NULL (I try it now but still does not work). How can do that?